# Checking with os.Stat vs just os.MkdirAll

Tags: go

I need to write to a file in a nested directory that may or may not exist.

At first, I checked if the folder existed via `os.Stat`, doing `os.MkdirAll` if it doesn't exist, and then opening and writing to a file.

I tried removing the os.Stat and just doing `os.MkdirAll`, and it appears to work - meaning `os.MkdirAll` is idempotent.

My question is, is there a benefit of doing the `os.Stat` check? Is it a much lighter operation than `os.MkdirAll`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing `MkdirAll` does is call `os.Stat` to check if the path exists and is a directory.

```
func MkdirAll(path string, perm FileMode) error {
    // Fast path: if we can tell whether path is a directory or file, stop with success or error.
    dir, err := Stat(path)
    if err == nil {
        if dir.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }
        return &PathError{"mkdir", path, syscall.ENOTDIR}
    }
    ...
```

From the docs:

> If path is already a directory, MkdirAll does nothing and returns nil.

So no, you don't need to call `os.Stat`.